# Refactorizar código en JS

Tags: php, javascript, nodejs, reactjs

```js
function capitalize(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
function accum(s) {
  let stringArray = s.split("");
  let result = []
  
  Aqui debo poner el codigo funcional

  return result.map(capitalize).join("-");
}
```

He intentado de todo para que me funcione este codigo. He avanzado lo siguiente:

```
result = 
 stringArray((string, i) => {
  let alpha = string.toUpperCase()

let first = string.repeat([i]).toLowerCase()
return alpha.concat(first)
})
```

ese fragmento de codigo iria en la parte donde se pondria el codigo funcional, pero no lo logro que funcione,alguna observacion sobre ello?

lo que quiero lograr es lo sgte::

```
accum("abcd") ⇨ "A-Bb-Ccc-Dddd"
accum("RqaEzty") ⇨ "R-Qq-Aaa-Eeee-Zzzzz-Tttttt-Yyyyyyy" 
accum("cwAt") ⇨ "C-Ww-Aaa-Tttt"
```

Comment: en qué parte de la pregunta son relevantes las etiquetas [tag:nodejs] y [tag:reactjs]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas tratando `stringArray` como si fuese una función cuando en realidad es un `array` que debe sobre el cual realizar la acción sobre cada una de las letras, de esta forma:

```
stringArray.map((letter, i) => letter.repeat(i + 1))
```

De esta manera obtienes todos los valores repetidos he incluso podrías sumar la función `concat` dentro del `map` para ahorrar pasos, quedando tu código de la siguiente manera:

```js
function capitalize(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
function accum(s) {
  let stringArray = s.split("");
  return stringArray
    .map((letter, index) => (
      capitalize(letter.repeat(index + 1))
    ))
    .join('-')

}
console.log(
  accum('abcd')
)
```